# Unity MapBox with custom width and height

Tags: unity-game-engine, mapbox

I am making a **Unity** app for **Android** and **iOS** and have a requirement to show map in a kind of frame.
For Showing map I am using **Mapbox** unity assets.

So I tried creating a parent game object and make the map child of it padding on all sides but when I run the scene map still loads fullscreen with no  padding at all. I tried changing the camera extent option of the abstract map class but the results were not good and when zoom in the map it actually goes out of bounds of my frame.
I also noticed that when I zoom in and out it actually changes the z axis position to do the same.
So I want to ask how to keep the width and height of the map fixed and make it zoom in and out in that particular area.

Below is the attached image of how I want to style the map.

[image: Map Image]

Answer (score -3):

yes sure !
first you watch video :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=28JTTXqMvOU
Then I'll explain if you have a problem !

Comment: This is not what I want. I am creating real map using mapbox sdk. Also this is an ar app

Comment: for create big map ? for create big map you can : make a minimap in Panel and resize & convert to MapBox

Comment: I want a map like the image posted in the question. The link that you gave is not related to real maps

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow as that link could go dead in the future and then your answer would contain no information. You should edit your answer to include the relevant information and provide the link *as supplemental context.*